# JavaScript split a string at each occurrence of

Tags: javascript, string, split

JavaScript, How can we split...

Input String: `12:002:204:457:109:40`

Output:

```
12:00
2:20
4:45
7:10
9:40
```

Comment: There isn't a good logical way to split those unless you make it so that they have leading 0s. Then you could split every 4 characters. I suggest you change your input method, it's not good.

Comment: I agree with you @Sterling Archer.

Comment: The logic seems to be that there are two numbers after each `:`, which is easily matched with a regex, see the answer of [Pranav C Balan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39498212/6738706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex [`/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gI8dH8/1).

```js
console.log(
  '12:002:204:457:109:40'.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/g)
)
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/gI8dH8/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```js
'12:002:204:457:109:40'.match(/(\d+:\d{2})/g).map(x => console.log(x))
```

```
(\d+:\d{2})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/O36bO8O0-XQw1cC2)

Further explanation: https://regex101.com/r/vV2wL5/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It is giving the exact O/P as per your need.I have tested it using alert(). Change it accordingly.

```
function aDarnal() {
  var s="12:002:204:457:109:40";
  var len= s.length;
   while(len >1)
   {
    var n = s.indexOf(":")+ 2;
    var x=  s.substr(0,n+1);
    alert(x);
    s=s.substr(n+1);
    len= s.length
   }
 }
```